# Is it possible to stop the xsp --nonstop process without using the kill command?

Tags: linux, mono, xsp

I have a process xsp4 running this way:

> xsp4 --port 8181 --nonstop &

Of couse, i can terminate it this way:

> kill $(lsof -t -i:8181)

But maybe there is some other, more correct way, which I do not know?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched some kind of solution for current question but didn't found an correct answer.
But later i suddenly found a way to kill server - by replacing a folder inside a container where the xsp4 was started `~/fixtures/code/xsp4 --port 8181 --nonstop &`. Every time when i'm replacing data inside that folder `rm -r -f fixtures/code/*` for example - i have to start server again.
Hope it will help you either some one.